# Django: Get Data from python method with jquery/js

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I've got a method where I loop through a .txt file and randomly create myself a code from different words inside that file. Now I'd like to somehow get that data/the code and call it with a js function. More specifically, when clicking on a button, it should always call that python method and give me the returned value, which I then can use to show it on my page.

in my `validators.py` I've got my method finished

```
def generate_code(request):
    words = open("words.txt").readlines()
    word_one = random.choice(words).rstrip('\n')
    word_two = random.choice(words).rstrip('\n')
    number = random.randint(0, 100)
    code = "{}-{}-{}".format(word_one, word_two, number)
    return JsonResponse(code)
```

in my urls.py:

```
url(r'form/generate/code/?$', views.generate_code),
```

But how do I call this function now and get the returned value to use it in my JS?

I know I've got to do something like

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '/api/form/generate/code/'
  data: ???,
  success: function(data) {
     console.warn(data)
 }
});
```

But what would my `data` be? Shouldn't that be my returned JsonResponse from the python method?

Comment: Post your view code please. Does it expect any get/post payload? If not, you don't need to send any `data` in your ajax call.

Comment: @Selcuk I've updated the view code, but not it doesnt expect any get/post payloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, just had to return my code with a HttpResponse instead of JsonResponse:

`return HttpResponse(json.dumps(code), content_type='application/json')`, remove the `data` from my ajax call and add a `datatype: 'json'` and it worked